Enable QuestDB compression on Mac
I want to use ZFS compression on my local environment, using a Macbook Pro M1. For my production environment I didn't have any issues by following the docs, as I have a dedicated EBS volume for the QDB_ROOT, but on my Macbook I have only my internal drive, and I don't know how I could create the ZFS unit there.
Is there any way I can do something like this on my local disk?
zpool create -m legacy -o feature@lz4_compress=enabled autoexpand=on -O compression=lz4 -t volume1 questdb-pool sdf


On Mac you can create a disk image using your local disk, then you can use that image. It took me a few attempts to get the right combination of parameters so I could use ZFS on top of the image, but this works and I can confirm data is compressed also on my development environment.
Edit: On the original post I forgot to add I had to install openzfs via brew install openzfs. Thanks user Victor for pointing this out!
# Create the disk image without a filesystem
hdiutil create -size 400m -type SPARSEBUNDLE -layout NONE -nospotlight zfsQuestdb

# Attach the disk image without mounting
hdiutil attach -nomount zfsQuestdb.sparsebundle

# Find the device name (assuming it's the last one, adjust if necessary)
DISK=$(diskutil list | grep "/dev/disk" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')

# Create the ZFS pool
sudo zpool create qdb_root $DISK

# Set ZFS properties
sudo zfs set compression=lz4 qdb_root

# Create the mounting directories in the home directory and assigning permissions for the local user
mkdir -p ~/data/qdb_root
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/data/qdb_root


# Create ZFS filesystem and set mount point
sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/Users/$(whoami)/data/qdb_root qdb_root/data

# Verify the setup
zfs list
zpool status


thanks for sharing. but I found neither zpool nor zfs in os ver12.6.3. can you help or suggest?

Sure. I forgot to add that I had to install first openzfs via brew install openzfs. Will edit the post to add it. Thanks for letting me know!

thank you for the updates. After install openzfs successfully, I cannot find zfs nor zpool via terminal. (it's been installed and ths os  rebooted, no zfs found in any bin folder).

no worries, and I found them under the folder /usr/local/zfs/bin/ which is unusual to me.
